# How can I get vertice and corresponding Attr in GraphX in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I can get a graph by running the following code:

```
graph = Graph(vertices, edges) // declare a graph
```

Then I can get vertices and attributes by:

```
graph.vertices.foreach(println)
```

After that maybe the output is:

```
(4,Attr(D,true,completed,Map(),Map()))
(1,Attr(A,null,null,Map(B -> null, C -> null),Map(B -> null, C -> null)))
(2,Attr(B,null,null,Map(C -> null, D -> null),Map(C -> null, D -> null)))
(3,Attr(C,null,null,Map(D -> null),Map(D -> null)))
(5,Attr(E,null,null,Map(),Map()))
```

The number in the bracket represents the node and the content in the Attr() are the attributes.
How can I get vertice and other info in GraphX in scala? Maybe

```
node.id = 4 
node.attributes = Attr(D,true,completed,Map(),Map())
```

or any functions can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The return value of `graph.vertices` is a VertexRDD, a RDD that contains already the id and the attributes of each node. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: Then how can I get the value of id and the value of Attr in scala? I'm a newbie in scala, and I want to turn these data into JSON format like`{4: {class: "D",  value: true, state: "completed"}}`.Can I format `graph.vertices` into a `Iterator`?

Comment: Please check out [graph.vertices.collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect():Array[T]). This method returns a standard Scala array

Comment: I know how to operate a graph in scala. Thanks!